# Magick.net no OpenMP?

Tags: magick.net, imagemagick.net

I started using Magick.net an it only performs tasks using one Thread.
Do I have to do something make it perform filter operations using multiple Threads?
Or is OpenMP not part of Magick.net?
Using ImageMagick from command line uses OpenMP and all cores flawlessly.

Just checked against GraphicsMagick's Magick.net. OpenMP working there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweeted to the Magick.NET dev and he confirmed, that Magick.NET does not have OpenMP. 
The GraphicsMagick version of Magick.NET does.
However in future releases even GM.NET will drop OpenMP as well, so check the changelog if you are reading this in the future.